# How to catch SqlException in LINQ to SQL

Tags: wpf, linq-to-sql, sqlexception, submitchanges

In my WPF application, I'm using LINQ to SQL, so when I call `SubmitChanges()`, it throws an exception, but I'm unable to catch it.

Here is the relevant code:

```
try
{
    FeatureDataContext.Features.InsertOnSubmit(newFeature);
    FeatureDataContext.SubmitChanges();
}
catch (SqlException sqlEx)
{
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("CreateNewFeature : " + sqlEx.Message);
}
```

And this is the exception which the above throws:

```
Exception Info: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
Stack:
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(System.Data.Linq.ConflictMode)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges()
   at [....]
```

How to catch the `SqlException` in WPF application?

I saw that `SubmitChanges()` doesn't throw any exception. But the code which raised exception points to is the code which calls `SubmitChanges()`.

---

EDIT:

The full exception is this:

```
Application: CompositeApplicationLauncher.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
Stack:
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(System.Data.Linq.ConflictMode)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges()
   at Runaware.Wpf.CompositeApplication.SessionReviewer.SessionDataProvider.CreateNewCategory(Runaware.InsightAnalysis.ApplicationFeatures.ObjectModel.ApplicationInfo)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.Commands.DelegateCommand`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Execute(System.__Canon)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.Commands.DelegateCommand`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].System.Windows.Input.ICommand.Execute(System.Object)
   at Runaware.Wpf.CompositeApplication.Commands.DelegateExecute.ExecuteCaller(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.InvokeClickAfterRender(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at Runware.Wpf.CompositeApplication.App.Main()
```

Comment: Could you include the full stack trace of the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the the the try-catch block you provided is inside the `CreateNewCategory` (looking at the stacktrace) method and the type of the exception being thrown is actually SqlException, then it should be caught.

Alternatively, if you want to catch all exceptions in the applications, you need to subscribe to the `Application.DispatcherUnhandledException` event for exceptions in the UI thread and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` for exceptions in other threads.

Comment: It should be noted that Application.DispatcherUnhandledException and AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException should only be used to log errors and let the app crash gracefully. Don't try to recover from an exception using these events.